# How to collaborate on a dynamic web project using eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, servlets, dynamic

I've created a project and pushed it to GitHub, here is the repo:
https://github.com/nati-elmaliach/CommunicationLTD-servlet

Now I want developers to clone this project and import it into eclipse as a dynamic web project version 2.5 since this is the template I used to create this project.

So what I did was: file -> import -> existing project into the workspace -> set the root directory

1. I don't have the option to run as  -> run on a server
2. the libraries are not included in the build path

I've also included the jars needed to run this project under `WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/`

How can I clone and start working on the project, assuming I already have a tomcat server installed and configured?

Comment: what is the right way to import this project to eclipse workspace and set it to a dynamic web project? also, what do you mean by drop the libraries to the WEB-INF/lib? I've included these libaries with my project, do i need to add them manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't commit the .settings folder. There's a file in there that indicates that it's a dynamic web project. You should also refer to the JRE from within the project by its Execution Environment, instead of the name of the JRE in your preferences--which would be pretty specific to your machine.

Comment: That did the trick, including the .setting folder made the import much simpler. also, can you elaborate on how to refer to the JRE  by its execution environment?

Comment: To borrow from another question, when picking your project's JRE System Library, pick the first option for that layer of indirection that makes it portable: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rzdkY.jpg . Each system will match the chosen execution environment to one of the JREs in that workspace's preferences (the matching is controllable from the Execution Environments preference page).